# I cloned a remote branch. How do I checkout master?

Tags: git, git-checkout

I cloned a remote branch with
`git clone --single-branch --branch <branchname> <remote-repo>` .
Now I want to checkout master. When I try `git checkout master` I get this error message: `error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git`.
How do I checkout master without having to clone it separately?

Comment: From the doc : "Further fetches into the resulting repository will only update the remote-tracking branch for the branch this option was used for the initial cloning.". You'll have to reclone without the option I'm afraid.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---no-single-branch) :

> "Further fetches into the resulting repository will only update the remote-tracking branch for the branch this option was used for the initial cloning."

You'll have to reclone without the option I'm afraid.

Note that **remote-tracking** branches are not **local** branches. Recloning won't create a local branch for each remote one, even *without* `--single-branch`

Comment: You don't really need to re-clone: see `git remote set-branches`.

Comment: @torek That's neat, I didn't know this [one](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emset-branchesem) but you're right it's indeed a better solution than re-cloning altogether. Thanks!